# How to validate JSON payload against OpenApi specification from Ruby?

Tags: ruby, openapi, json-api

I have HTTP request payload structured according to [jsonapi.org](https://jsonapi.org/) guidelines:

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "employee",
    "attributes": {
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",
    }
  }
}
```

then I have [OpenApi](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/about/) specification (yaml) of this payload:

```
employee: 
  type: object
  required: [data]
  properties:
    data:
      type: object
      properties:
        type:
          type: string
          enum: [employee]
        attributes: 
          type: object
          required: [firstName, lastName]
          properties:
            firstName:
              type: string
              example: 'John'
            lastName:
              type: string
              example: 'Doe'
```

and what I want is to validate the payload against the specification (from Ruby/Rails).

there exist [openapi3_parser gem](https://github.com/kevindew/openapi3_parser#validating), but that one seems to be capable only to validate the specification, not the actual payload.

then, there are [jsonapi.org payload deserializers](https://jsonapi.org/implementations/#server-libraries-ruby), but those do not seem to take care about OpenApi formal specification at all.

I use OpenApi to describe the payload becuase I get http API docs for free via Swagger.

Answer (score 1):

it can be achieved by using [json-schema](https://github.com/ruby-json-schema/json-schema#basic-usage), e.g.:

```
errors = JSON::Validator.fully_validate(schema, payload)
```

(it is working for me with json-schema gem 2.8.1, schema itself is written in openapi v 2.0)

Comment: how can I do this? `json-schema` is not capable to validate against openapi schema. It supports json-schema up to `draft4`.

Comment: You can either upgrade to using OpenAPI 3.1 which is now is a JSON Schema. .And use validator in [different language](https://json-schema.org/implementations.html)  as there is no ruby validator for JSON Schema 2019 yet. 

Or upgrade to 3.0,  then use [OpenAPI to JSON Schema coverter](https://github.com/openapi-contrib/openapi-schema-to-json-schema/)
and [json_schemer](https://github.com/davishmcclurg/json_schemer) ruby gem that supports JSON Schema draft-7

Answer (score 1):

This gem https://github.com/interagent/committee validates requests/responses based off of an open api spec you provide.